# Winform class to main program

Tags: c#, winforms, class

How would I get the main program to recognize that I have an outside class that I need to refer to?

I have created a class "Hello"
and I need to refer to an instance of the class

`private Hello hello1 = new Hello();`

But when I write this code out, it does not recognize "Hello" to begin with..

Comment: You should give us a better clue of what is wrong. Is your code in the same project or in the different one? What is the access modifier of your `Hello` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hello class is in the same project with main program you can do it by just adding a using statement as raphael mentioned. If they are not on the same project first you should add reference of the project that includes hello class. Lets say you got 2 projects. 1 main (including your main program) second is hello project(including your hello class). In visual studio extend main project, right click to the references and select "add reference" then select the hello project.

hope it was clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

If the Hello class is not in the same project has your Form, you have to add a reference to the "Hello class"'s project.

But first, just check that they're in the same namespace. If not, add a

`using <namespace of your HelloClass>;` in your WinForm class.

Or change the namespace of your Hello class to be the same as the Winform's one.

(The namespace's name is appearing just after the "using"s declaration : `namespace <name of the namespace> {`)